# how to filter rows within a datagridview in vb.net? (Why isn't .RowFilter a member of DataGridView?)

Tags: vb.net

I'm just not used to the syntax of VB.net, so would really appreciate how I would filter a datagridview according to a certain row within it? Why isn't .RowFilter a member of DataGridView?

Comment: How are you loading it? Filter that.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Because you filter the DataSet/DataTable that is backing the `DataGridView`. Try creating a new copy the the `DataSource`, filtering it and then setting the `DataGridView.DataSource` to the filtered copy.

Comment: Because a **DataGridView** is just a placeholder for data, not filtering. Of course you can handle all of that if you want. Otherwise, that's why there's a **DataView** to filter the data.

Comment: If the grid is bound to a `DataSet`, `DataTable` or `DataView` then you can use the `RowFilter` of the appropriate `DataView` to filter the data.  Better yet, bind the source to a `BindingSource` and bind that to the grid, then use its `Filter` property to filter the data.

Comment: If your source is not one of those or some other type that implements the `IBindingListView` interface then that option is not available.  In that case, you can do your own filtering via LINQ or some other method and change the `DataSource` each time or else you can actually loop through the rows in the grid and set the `Visible` property of each one as required.